# Realign Remote Desktop session icons to physical desktop's

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Somehow, the desktop icons for a workstation that i frequently Remote-desktop into has been rearranged to the right side. I don't know how/when that happened, but only discovered when I minimised all windows (which i seldom do).

[image]

The good thing is, when i log on physically to the workstation, the desktop arrangement is back to the regular alignment. So there is a "disconnect" between Windows 7's physical layout vs virtual RDP layout.

Now the question is, how is it possible for me to get the RDP layout to "reset" and follow the physical alignment again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no such thing as "physical" or "RDP" layout, or one layout "following" another. There are only different screen resolutions, each of which has its own icon positions stored in the registry at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop
```

For example, if your screen (whether RDP or physical) is 1280x1024, the positions are stored in the value `ItemPos1280x1024(1)`. Delete it and the icons will be put in the default places.

Comment: Physically i have three monitors 1920x1200 + two 1680x1050 by the sides. The virtual desktop is just the single 1920x1200 layout. So I am not entirely sure which entry should represent my three physical monitors...